# Android JSON parse troubles

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have a web service returning the following string verbatim:

> "{\"type\":\"youtube\", \"data\":\"http://66.84.12.156/android/?x=12&uid=4&lati=40.73972412&longi=-73.99234962&y=14&pixel_id=7224&pid=4&surface_id=7&fn=showHTML&data_id=7224&data=kT2UQ8TYMpk\",\"pixel_id\":\"471\",\"x\":\"12\",\"y\":\"14\",\"pid\":\"4\",\"surface_id\":\"7\",\"data_id\":\"7224\",\"user_id\":\"4\"}"

Code looks lke:

```
dataScanner.client = new DefaultHttpClient();
dataScanner.post = new HttpPost("http://someurl/somepage.php");
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(userKV));
Log.d("DST Scanner", "post string:" + post.toString());
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        Log.d("DST Scanner", "Post Response (string)" + builder.toString());
        //JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(builder.toString());
        finalResult = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
```

I've tried many different formats (escaped quotes, unescaped quotes, no surrounding quotes, escaped forward slashes), but I keep getting this error:

> org.json.JSONException: Value {"type":"youtube", "data":"http://66.84.12.156/android/?x=12&uid=4&lati=40.73972412&longi=-73.99234962&y=14&pixel_id=7224&pid=4&surface_id=7&fn=showHTML&data_id=7224&data=kT2UQ8TYMpk","pixel_id":"471","x":"12","y":"14","pid":"4","surface_id":"7","data_id":"7224","user_id":"4"} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Everything looks fine to me, but I've been looking at this so long I wouldn't be surprised if there's some silly thing I'm doing..

Comment: The webservice is broken. The quotes in the json string should NOT be escaped like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to json, but all of my JSON start and end with "[" and "]" and I use PHP to echo out the json_encode method.

On Android side i use:

```
    try {
        URL pHH = new URL("http://192.168.1.5/somephp.php");
        URLConnection WC = pHH.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new              InputStreamReader(WC.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(line);

            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                items[i] = jo.getString("title");
                thumbnails[i] = jo.getString("thumb");
                links[i] = jo.getString("link");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] utf8 = null;
            StringBuilder properString = new StringBuilder("");

            utf8 = Response.toCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < utf8.length; i++) {
                if ((int) utf8[i] < 65000) {
                    properString.append(utf8[i]);
                }
            }
  System.out.println("Response of Login::"
                        + properString.toString());
```